# Como fazer uma régua vertical de orientação com o mesmo numero de linhas de texto importado vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Estou a construir um editor de texto e preciso de fazer uma regua vertical com o mesmo numero de linhas de texto importado.
Já sei como obter o numero de linhas do texto importado mas nao encontrei soluçao nenhuma para fazer uma régua vertical com o mesmo numero de linhas que o texto importado.
Com o codigo actual so mostra os numeros ate 20 e o texto tem mais linhas
como mostra na imagem
[image: ímagem da aplicaçao com o codigo actual]
este e o código que uso para obter o numero de linhas

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
Dim datax = DateAndTime.Now
Dim time As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim format As String = "d M yyyy d HH:mm"
Dim lineCount As Integer

Private Sub CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Ensure that text is selected in the text box.   
    If TextBox1.SelectionLength > 0 Then
        ' Copy the selected text to the Clipboard.
        TextBox1.Copy()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub PastToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PastToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Determine if there is any text in the Clipboard to paste into the text box.
    If Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) = True Then
        ' Determine if any text is selected in the text box.
        If TextBox1.SelectionLength > 0 Then
            ' Ask user if they want to paste over currently selected text.
            If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to paste over current selection?", _
                "Cut Example", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.No Then
                ' Move selection to the point after the current selection and paste.
                TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.SelectionStart + _
                    TextBox1.SelectionLength
            End If
        End If
        ' Paste current text in Clipboard into text box.
        TextBox1.Paste()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Ensure that text is currently selected in the text box.   
    If TextBox1.SelectedText <> "" Then
        ' Cut the selected text in the control and paste it into the Clipboard.
        TextBox1.Cut()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UndoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UndoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ' Determine if last operation can be undone in text box.   
    If TextBox1.CanUndo = True Then
        ' Undo the last operation.
        TextBox1.Undo()
        ' Clear the undo buffer to prevent last action from being redone.
        TextBox1.ClearUndo()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    a = TextBox2.Text
    b = InStr(TextBox1.Text, a)
    If b Then
        TextBox1.Focus()
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = b - 1
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = Len(a)
    Else
        MsgBox("No words")
    End If

    Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Confirm Replace?", _
                          "Title", _
                          MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)

    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then
        'Update data here
    Else
        'Nothing
    End If

    Dim str As String
    str = TextBox2.Text
    If str.Contains(TextBox2.Text) = True Then
        MsgBox("Your Word Its Present In This Text " & ("(") & TextBox2.Text & ")")

        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Your Word Its Not Present In This Text " & ("(") & TextBox2.Text & ")")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim a As String
    Dim b As String
    a = TextBox2.Text
    b = InStr(TextBox1.Text, a)
    If b Then
        TextBox1.Focus()
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = b - 1
        TextBox1.SelectionLength = Len(a)
    Else
        MsgBox("No words")
    End If
    'Dim counter as Integer
    'Create a string array and store the contents of the Lines property.
    ' Dim tempArray() As String
    ' tempArray = TextBox1.Lines

    'Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window.
    ' For counter = 0 To tempArray.GetUpperBound(0)

    'TextBox1.Text = tempArray(counter)
    'Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    SelecionarLinha2()
    TrocarLinha2PorLinha1()
End Sub
Private Sub SelecionarLinha2()

    ' Primeiro é necessário verificar se há pelo menos duas linhas.
    If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 1 Then
        ' Seleciona trecho do texto do controle começando no
        ' primeiro caractere da segunda linha (lineNumber=1).
        TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(1), TextBox1.Lines(1).Length)
        ' Se o foco não for enviado para o controle TextBox, a seleção não aparecerá.
        TextBox1.Focus()
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TrocarLinha2PorLinha1()

    ' Primeiro é necessário verificar se há pelo menos duas linhas.
    If TextBox1.Lines.Count > 1 Then
        Dim troca As String
        ' Quando a propriedade Lines é criada automaticamente a partir
        ' do texto digitado no controle, o array retornado por ela é
        ' apenas uma cópia somente leitura das linhas do controle,
        ' então, o texto não pode ser alterado diretamente na propriedade,
        ' por isso é necessário usar um array temporário.
        Dim linhas() As String = TextBox1.Lines

        ' Troca a segunda linha pela primeira linha.    
        troca = linhas(1)
        linhas(1) = linhas(0)
        linhas(0) = troca

        ' Devolve o array modificado para o controle.    
        TextBox1.Lines = linhas
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub SelecionarLinha2_JeitoAntigo()

    Dim posQuebraDeLinha As Integer = -1
    Dim firstCharIndex As Integer = -1
    Dim lineTwoLength As Integer = 0

    ' Busca pela quebra de linha da primeira linha.
    posQuebraDeLinha = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf)
    If posQuebraDeLinha < 0 Then Return
    ' Índice do primeiro caractere da segunda linha.
    firstCharIndex = posQuebraDeLinha + 2   '2 = Len(vbCrLf)

    ' Busca pela quebra de linha da segunda linha.
    posQuebraDeLinha = TextBox1.Text.IndexOf(vbCrLf, firstCharIndex)
    If posQuebraDeLinha < 0 Then posQuebraDeLinha = TextBox1.TextLength

    ' Calcula o comprimento do texto na segunda linha.
    lineTwoLength = posQuebraDeLinha - firstCharIndex

    TextBox1.Select(firstCharIndex, lineTwoLength)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub TrocarLinha2PorLinha1_JeitoAntigo()

    Dim troca As String
    ' Divide o texto usando a sequência de CarriageReturn (13) + LineFeed (10)
    ' como separador, resultando em um array em que cada item é uma linha.
    Dim linhas() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(vbCrLf)

    If linhas.Count > 1 Then
        troca = linhas(1)
        linhas(1) = linhas(0)
        linhas(0) = troca

        ' Junta de volta as linhas do array, usando de novo a sequência
        ' de CarriageReturn (13) + LineFeed (10) como separador.
        TextBox1.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, linhas)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub OpenToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OpenToolStripMenuItem.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text File"
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

    Dim textFile As StreamReader

    textFile = File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    TextBox1.Text = textFile.ReadToEnd()

    textFile.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    TextBox1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    lineCount = TextBox1.Lines.Count
End Sub

Public Function RemoveAcentos(ByVal texto As String) As String
    Dim charFrom As String = "ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ"
    Dim charTo As String = "SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy"
    For i As Integer = 0 To charFrom.Length - 1
        texto = Replace(texto, charFrom(i), charTo(i))
    Next
    Return texto
End Function

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    TextBox1.Text = RemoveAcentos(TextBox1.Text.ToString)
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackgroundColorToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ColorDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.BackColor = ColorDialog1.Color
End Sub

Private Sub FontToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FontToolStripMenuItem.Click
    FontDialog1.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.Font = FontDialog1.Font
End Sub

Private Sub FontColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FontColorToolStripMenuItem.Click
    ColorDialog2.ShowDialog()
    TextBox1.ForeColor = ColorDialog2.Color
End Sub

Private Sub InsertDateAndTimeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InsertDateAndTimeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'TextBox1.Text &= Environment.NewLine & time.ToString(format)
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(0, time.ToString(format) + vbNewLine)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Me.Text = time.ToString(format)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                             Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    SyncLineNumbers()
    Dim newHeight As Integer = ListBox1.ItemHeight * ListBox1.Items.Count
    If newHeight > Me.Height Then
        ListBox1.Height = newHeight
        TextBox1.Height = newHeight
    End If
    ListBox1.SelectedIndex = TextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(TextBox1.SelectionStart)
End Sub

Private Sub SyncLineNumbers()
    If TextBox1.Lines.Count <> ListBox1.Items.Count Then
        Do While TextBox1.Lines.Count > ListBox1.Items.Count
            ListBox1.Items.Add((ListBox1.Items.Count + 1).ToString)
        Loop

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use uma estrutura de controle de fluxo For-Next. 
O código dentro do bloco for-next será executado X vezes de acordo com a quantidade de linhas encontradas no textbox1. E para cada vez que for executado, a variável numeroLinha assumira o proximo valor numérico. Portanto na primeira vez ela vale 1, na segunda 2 e assim por diante.

Ex:

```
For numeroLinha As Integer = 1 To TextBox1.Lines.Count
    'use o numeroLinha na sua lógica. 
Next
```

Comment: obrigado mas como posso desenhar elas verticalmente em um gropbox?

Comment: pra te ajudar na parte visual eu precisaria ver melhor como está a estrutura do seu formulário não tem como postar mais partes do projeto?

Comment: Sim claro vou editar para postar o codigo

Comment: de facto esta foi a tentativa que fiz mas so mostra os numeros ate 20 vou editar para postar a imagem tambem

Comment: de facto já percebi qual e o erro e que não conta as linhas vazias e eu preciso que ele conte também as  linhas vazias